# Bitmaps to scroll across the screen using canvas Android

Tags: android, android-canvas

i am trying to get 2 bitmaps side by side to scroll across a screen.

My code

```
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)firstDrawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)secondDrawable).getBitmap();
    invalidateSelf();

    if (x< 0) {
        x = this.getIntrinsicWidth();
    } else {
        x -= xVelocity;
        if ((x > this.getIntrinsicWidth() - firstDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
           //x = xDirection ;
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x , y, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, x + bitmap.getWidth(), y, null);
```

I can see the first image scroll across but when it gets to the second image the animation stops, ideally i would like the images to loop constantly. Thanks

Comment: What method is this in? Where is x getting updated? Why are you re-defining and allocating the same bitmaps over and over again? And then why are you invaliding before you draw on the canvas?